# Matching/snapping two shapefiles using node and snapping tools

Tags: qgis, editing, snapping, qgis-2.6

I am trying to edit my shapefiles through QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton. I used the node tools to snap the necessary nodes to eliminate spaces between two shapefiles. However, while doing it I noticed that an extra line came out. Please see image below - the line that appeared when I'm editing is pointed out by the right and left arrows. I am also using the snapping tools while doing this.

How do I remove these two lines?

[image]

Comment: I've made some edits to rephrase what you were asking based on context in the question. Please feel free to revert the edit if you actually meant something different. It appears that while you were adjusting the vertices/nodes of one layer, one was accidentally snapped to the wrong vertex of the layer you're trying to align to. You should just be able to grab that vertex with the node tool and move it up to snap to another between the two where that line diverges from the one you're trying to trace. You could also just delete that vertex, though it will result in a straight segment.